# Scrapy Missing one Positional Argument Response

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, scrapy

I want to Store All the links inside a **my_links** variable. But one i tried to store they gives me error. Missing one Positional Argument **response**. I am new to scrapy... Help Please... Here is the My Code

```py
import scrapy
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess


class Udemy_Scraper(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "udemy_scraper"
    start_urls = ['https://couponscorpion.com/']
    def parse(self, response):
        for links in response.xpath('//div[@class="rh-post-wrapper"]'):
            yield {
                'name': links.xpath('.//a/text()').extract(),
            }
    my_links = parse()
```

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to call `parse` method as it is the callback method and gets called for all the URLs in the `start_urls` list. You can make a list at spider level. This will work.

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess


class Udemy_Scraper(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "udemy_scraper"
    my_links = []
    start_urls = ['https://couponscorpion.com/']
    def parse(self, response):
        for links in response.xpath('//div[@class="rh-post-wrapper"]'):
            self.my_links + =[{'name': links.xpath('.//a/text()').extract()}]
        yield self.my_links
```